# Amazon Web Service PowerShell Credentials setup Errors

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to set up my AWS on my local machine through windows PowerShell, it gives me the following error message;

```
    PS C:\> Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} -SecretKey {AAAAAAAAAAAAA} -Stor
eAs {default}
Set-AWSCredentials : Cannot evaluate parameter 'AccessKey' because its argument is specified as a script block and
there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:1 char:31
+ Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} -SecretKey {AAAAAAAAAAAA ...
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Set-AWSCredentials], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Amazon.PowerShell.Common.SetCredentialsCmdlet
```

And my Powershell Version is following;

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need to drop the brackets from your code, the documentation from amazon that comes up first in google includes them for some reason but if you check out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Set-AWSCredentials.html and the examples near the bottom you'll see that the function is really expecting them in a string just like any other powershell cmdlet.

```
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA -SecretKey AAAAAAAAAAAAA -StoreAs default
```

Should do the trick for you (if there are spaces in anything make sure to wrap the string in quotes)

Comment: PSD1 can be used for config:  http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PowerShell-Configuration-Data/